# Hiding Sharepoint Calculated Column when editing page in datasheet view

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint calculated column which shows the percentage completed using some colors(did it with javascript). Now i want this to be made read-only.... i.e... whenever i edit the page in datasheet view,the column should not appear... any code with javascript will be helpfull...
Please help me in this

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the column hidden . follow the article link below to make a column hidden from add/edit forms

[Hide / Remove Title column from Sharepoint List](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/10/hide-remove-title-column-from.html)

Comment: Hi Brad, Please help me with a question on list filter on a calculated column - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134641/sharepoint-calculated-column-filter-shows-formula-instead-of-values

Answer (score -1):

The columns shown in the datasheet view are those chosen in the View it's based on. Simply modify the View (from the View drop-down on the ribbon), and deselect that column.

If you need it to *never* be shown, then Ashutosh's answer would certainly be preferable.